# unable to add image in velocity

Tags: java, velocity

hi friends i'm having problem in adding image when i use Virtual macro temp let URL i use `<img src="https://localhost:8443/roswellpark/images/logo.png"  width="100" height="100">` but it automatically converts in gmail like `<img width="100" height="100" src="https://ci6.googleusercontent.com/proxy/OqeDs7DeqQwo6y0m3gb4nL8CUT02UK1VpGsSgt84p1w8YzZjRzPt4B9A2d9QpuKgVi7xLZ82s_c3f2jdycg4wQQegCVK_FMy=s0-d-e1-ft#https://localhost:8443/roswellpark/images/logo.png" class="CToWUd">` and image is not visible in mail hope this is not a repeated question please help or give any suggestion thank you...

Comment: You generate a mail message? And the message contains an image located at localhost...?

Comment: yes i generate email message and want to put logo as image in templat

Comment: You can embed the image in the mail or try to use an image accessable from internet like   https://www.roswellpark.org/sites/all/themes/responsewell/images/rpci-logo.png

Comment: Thank you soo much its working can you tell me how can i get this image from local host

Comment: Do you want it to test your mails?

Comment: Sorry i'm not getting ...

Comment: Will the image be accessable in produktion from the internet? If yes then in development you send the mails to localhost and have a look with fakesmtp (https://nilhcem.github.io/FakeSMTP/). If not you must embed the image in the email. Then I need to know more of your code for sending email to help.

Comment: Got it hank images accessible in production  from internet thank you for help thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
enter code here
#set($filesite="https://localhost:8443")
<img src="$filesite/roswellpark/images/logo.png"  width="100" height="100">
```

It will work